# Cartoon where the main characters were from different time periods

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

The only thing I seem to remember about this cartoon is it reminded me of *Indian in the Cupboard* and the main characters were 3 men from different time periods.

- One was an Indian (Native American)
- One was I think a Civil War solider
- The other may have been an American soldier but I'm not sure about that one

They all used at least at one point musket rifles and I remember they were usually in a forest being chased down by someone they interfered with, the only group I recall was the native Americans enemies or allies for some reason.

Comment: It kind of reminds me of the Family Guy Episode Life Of Brian. In it's opening Brian and Stewie flee from Native Americans after they used Stewie's time machine to interfere with their history.

Comment: I never really watched family guy back than and the animation was semi-realistic looking people kinda like G I Joe to an extent but not exactly.

Comment: i meant that Family Guy may have based that opening sequence on the cartoon your are referencing. Maybe you can trace the origin through it, or maybe somebody else here can.